# Google Dataflow issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-dataflow

We are newly implementing DataWareHouse on Google bigquery and all our sources are on prim databases. So we are using dataflow for ETL and Maven with the Apache Beam SDK in order to run a 30 pipelines on Google Cloud Dataflow service.

```
package com.google.cloud.teleport.templates; 
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.io.DynamicJdbcIO;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.common.JdbcConverters;
import com.google.cloud.teleport.util.KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.PipelineResult;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.TableRowJsonCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider;

public class MToBQ {

  private static ValueProvider<String> maybeDecrypt(
      ValueProvider<String> unencryptedValue, ValueProvider<String> kmsKey) {
    return new KMSEncryptedNestedValueProvider(unencryptedValue, kmsKey);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JdbcConverters.JdbcToBigQueryOptions options =
        PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args)
            .withValidation()
            .as(JdbcConverters.JdbcToBigQueryOptions.class);

    run(options);
  }
  private static PipelineResult run(JdbcConverters.JdbcToBigQueryOptions options) {
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
    pipeline
       
        .apply(
            "source",
            DynamicJdbcIOMiles.<TableRow>read()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(
                    DynamicJdbcIOMiles.DynamicDataSourceConfiguration.create(
                            options.getDriverClassName(),
                            maybeDecrypt(options.getConnectionURL(), options.getKMSEncryptionKey()))
                        .withUsername(
                            maybeDecrypt(options.getUsername(), options.getKMSEncryptionKey()))
                        .withPassword(
                            maybeDecrypt(options.getPassword(), options.getKMSEncryptionKey()))
                        .withDriverJars(options.getDriverJars())
                        .withConnectionProperties(options.getConnectionProperties()))
                .withQuery("select * from abcc")
                .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())
                .withRowMapper(JdbcConverters.getResultSetToTableRow()))
        .apply(
            "Target",
            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .withoutValidation()
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                .withCustomGcsTempLocation(options.getBigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory())
                .to("dev-27:staging.STG_ABC"));
 pipeline
        .apply(
            "SOURCE",
            DynamicJdbcIOMiles.<TableRow>read()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(
                    DynamicJdbcIOMiles.DynamicDataSourceConfiguration.create(
                            options.getDriverClassName(),
                            maybeDecrypt(options.getConnectionURL(), options.getKMSEncryptionKey()))
                        .withUsername(
                            maybeDecrypt(options.getUsername(), options.getKMSEncryptionKey()))
                        .withPassword(
                            maybeDecrypt(options.getPassword(), options.getKMSEncryptionKey()))
                        .withDriverJars(options.getDriverJars())
                        .withConnectionProperties(options.getConnectionProperties()))
                .withQuery("SELECT * FROM XYZ")
                .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of())
                .withRowMapper(JdbcConverters.getResultSetToTableRow()))
 
        .apply(
            "TARGET",
            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .withoutValidation()
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                .withCustomGcsTempLocation(options.getBigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory())
                .to("dev-27:staging.STG_XYZ")); 
    return pipeline.run();
  }
}
```

if the data in the tables is less, then it is running successfully. If the data is in millions, it is throwing error like below

```
org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:107)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: (g)RPC timed out
```

To compile and run the main method of the Java class with arguments, I am executing the following command.

```
mvn compile exec:java \
-Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.MToBQ \
-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false \
-Dexec.args=" \
--project= dev-27 \
--region=australia-southeast1 \
--workerMachineType=n1-highmem-8 \
--workerDiskType=compute.googleapis.com/projects/dev-27/zones/australia-southeast1-c/diskTypes/pd-ssd \
--diskSizeGb=50 \
--stagingLocation=gs://dev-dataset/Data/stagingCustomDataFlow/MToBQ \
--tempLocation=gs://dev-dataset/Data/temp \
--templateLocation=gs://dev-dataset/Data/templatesCustomDataFlow/MToBQ/MToBQ.json \
--experiments=upload_graph \
--runner=DataflowRunner" **
```

Kindly let me know if I am it right. what are the right arguments and can dataflow execute multiple pipelines parallel?

Comment: Is the pipeline stopping or throwing many exceptions like the above?

Comment: Where is your data located? What is your goal? Transfer your data from your database to BigQuery?

Comment: @rmesteves data is located in sql server and want to transfer to BQ.

Comment: @bigbounty it is throwing exceptions and failing after sometime.

Comment: @Jambal Do you need to load only once or will you update data constantly? If you doing a single load one simpler approach is exporting a file in your SQL Server and loading it on BigQuery

Comment: @rmesteves Its a every day datawarehouse load.

Comment: In this case, have you taken a  look at BigQuery Transfer service (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/transfer-service-overview)

Comment: WIth BQ Transfer Service you can use partner transfer sources like Fivetran (https://fivetran.com/blog/dts-announcement) that does exactly what you want. This would be the plug and play solution for this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217527/discussion-between-rmesteves-and-jambal).

Answer (score 0):

I think it will throw error because its trying to access a source with a single thread connection possibly (which will choke when large dataset comes in), I am not sure how you have configured source read, but would suggest you to make it parallel. This will read those dataset at source in multiple threads and thereby scaling too.